# Api with Authorize attribute not working with identity server 4 and Web form client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3, identityserver4

I have created Identity server 4 RC 3 with asp.net identity and in memory clients and scopes. I have created a secure api and an mvc client. i am trying to call api from MVC client and it works well. Now, I created a web form client ( asp.net 4.5) and configured opendidopetions in it, i am trying to call api from webform client but getting 401, I see that when api is hit then isauthenticated = false and Name is null in api user.claims. i tried to log the error and it says: "[Information] "Bearer" was not authenticated. Failure message: "No SecurityTokenValidator available for token: ". My web form client has these options:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",              
            ClientId = "mvcClient",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002",             
            ResponseType = "code id_token token",               
            Scope = "openid profile NamfusAPI offline_access roles",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",            


            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {     ..... // code to authenitcate
```

This is api code:

```
 public IActionResult Get()
{
return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new {c.Type, c.Value });
}
```

i see claims is empty and user.isauthenticated is false

Comment: I noticed that when role:"admin" is added in JWT token, then this causes problem. how to parse/validate jwt token with admin side?